# How do I bump a question?

Tags: support, faq, questions

- How do I bump a question, here?
- Is there any suggested way, or a preferable way?
- When is it appropriate to bump a question?

Answer (score 5):

The Stack Exchange engine has some stuff that will "bump" some questions. Also some rewards in the form of badges exist when you answer older questions.

If your question isn't answered, you should try to review it to see if you can improve it. It could be that your question:

- wasn't clear enough
- needed more background information
- had too much code example
- was very hard and thus has not been answered yet
- was lacking commitment on your part

There are several ways of improving the answer rate for questions. This is a site where people answer questions because they want to, so you should have those people in mind when you ask a question.

If you are bumping your question because you didn't get an answer that you consider satisfactory, then look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty.

> What if I don’t get a good answer?
>
> First, make sure you've [asked a good question](/questions/how-to-ask). 
>
>     **In order to get good answers to your question, you may need to put additional 
>
>     effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. 
>
>     Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will 
>
>     naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.**
>
> If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you
>
>     can help by offering a bounty. Slice off anywhere
>
>     from +50
>
>     to +500
>
>     of your own hard-earned reputation and attach it to *any* question as a bounty.
>
>     The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists,
>
>     and it will also be visible on the [home page Featured tab](/?tab=featured)
>
>     for the duration of the bounty period.

Generally speaking, you should not bump a question just for for its own sake. The system provides automatic bumping as a side effect of something you do that warrants folks taking another look at your question (improving the post, for example). But it would be abusive to continually bump your question as a means to simply gain more audience. Improving your post is the best way of improving your chances to get an answer.